# fast filesystem path matching with some pattern (but no wildchar)

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

Assume a set of (Unix) paths, such as

```
/usr
/lib
/var/log
/home/myname/somedir
....
```

given a path `/some/path`, I want to test whether this `/some/path` matches any of that in the path set above, and, by "match", I mean

1. `/some/path` is exactly one of the path above, or
2. it is the a subpath of one of the path above.

I know I can split the path by `/` and do string matching one by one, but I want to do this very fast, probably by using some hashing technique or something similar such that I can transform those string matching to some integer matching.

Are there any algorithms for that? Or, is there any proof that it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

### Hash table approach

Since paths are generally not very deep, you may be able to afford storing all possible matching subpaths.

For every path in the input set add every its subpath to a hash table. For example, this set:

```
/usr
/lib
/var/log
/home/myname/somedir
```

will produce this table:

```
hash0 -> /usr
hash1 -> /lib
hash2 -> /var
hash3 -> /var/log
hash4 -> /home
hash5 -> /home/myname
hash6 -> /home/myname/somedir
```

Now the search query boils down to finding an exact match in this hash table. String comparison will only be needed in case of a hash collision.

One major drawback of this method is that in the general case it needs superlinear amount of memory (with respect to the size of the input set).

Consider a 600 characters-long path:

```
[400characterlongprefix]/a/a/a/...[100 times].../a/a/a/
```

And the corresponding table that contains 50500 characters in total:

```
hash0   -> [400characterlongprefix]
hash1   -> [400characterlongprefix]/a
hash2   -> [400characterlongprefix]/a/a
...
hash100 -> [400characterlongprefix]/a/a/a/...[100 times].../a/a/a/
```

### Trie approach

**Precomputation step**

1. Split every path in the set to its components.
2. Assign every distinct component an index and add the pair (component, index) to a hash table.
3. For every path, add the sequence of its component indices to a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

**Example**

Input set:

```
/usr
/var/log
/home/log/usr
```

Component indices:

```
usr  -> 0
var  -> 1
log  -> 2
home -> 3
```

Prefix tree:

```
0            // usr
1 -> 2       // var, log
3 -> 2 -> 0  // home, log, usr
```

**Search query**

1. Split the path to its components.
2. For every component find its index in the hash table.
3. If one of the components does not have a corresponding index, report no match.
4. Search the prefix tree for the sequence of component indices.